# Add omitted ? to URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a website with a CMS that reads the page as the name of the query string, e.g. 
`http://exmaple.com/?pagename`. I am trying to create a rewrite rule to rewrite it to with the `?`.

So, a user types in `/pagename` and is really taken to `/?pagename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: Note to the person who edited my answer: The URI *does* sometimes start with a slash, depending on what version of Apache it is. That's why the `?`, so it works in Apache 1.x and 2.x.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have tried this solution and it just creates a redirecting error, any ideas?

Comment: No, it only depends on whether the rule is used in an .htaccess file or in the server/virtual host configuration.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer this after your reply, I must have lost the notification somewhere. Thanks with your help and some further reading I got it to work, and the error i meantioned was caused by a conflicting rule from another redirect. The variation I used was a minor change to the last line to make it -------- RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]. Thanks for your help, and sorry for the long wait. Oli